# Viewing Linux Programmer's Manual when multiple pages bear the same name

Tags: command-line, man

I want to view the `read` page of the `Linux Programmer's Manual`. When I type `man read` I get the `read` page of the `General Commands Manual`.

Looking at the `man --help` I realized I could view all `man` pages for a query but that entails viewing them all one by one until I hit the one I'm looking for. Not really efficient.

How can I specify which manual I want to query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already know the section of the manual page you want to view, you can pass that as a parameter to `man`. For example, to view the manual page for `read` in section 2:

```
man 2 read
```

The sections are as follows (this list taken from the manual page for `man` itself):

1. Executable programs or shell commands
2. System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
3. Library calls (functions within program libraries)
4. Special files (usually found in /dev)
5. File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
6. Games
7. Miscellaneous (including  macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
8. System administration commands (usually only for root)
9. Kernel routines [Non standard]